# openerp - res.partner: default value depending on company type

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9

When creating a new contact, I would like to set "Customer" to True and "supplier" to False if the contact is "Individual" and vice versa: if the contact is Company : Set "customer" to False and "supplier" to True.

I've tried to make some changes in xml file so far but nothing happns..

```
<field name="supplier">{[('is_company','=', True)],'default_customer': 0,'default_supplier': 1} </field>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Hereafter my .py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date, time
from openerp import api 


class mypartner_custom(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    _columns = {

            'plafond_credit' : fields.float(string = 'Plafond Crédit',digits=(6,2)),
            'cin' : fields.char(string = 'CIN', size=15),


            }
mypartner_custom()

@api.onchange('is_company')
def change_company_type(self):
   if self.is_company == True:
      self.customer = False
      self.supplier = True
   else :
      self.customer = True
      self.supplier = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onchange method :

```
@api.onchange('company_type')
def change_company_type(self):
   if self.company_type == 'person':
      self.customer = True
      self.supplier = False
   else :
      self.customer = True
      self.supplier = True
```

Don't forget about the default values as this method is executed only when company_type value is changed..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
I really don't understand why It does not work (nothing happens actually)

I have tried the onchange decorator with this code is_company field 

@api.onchange('is_company')
def change_company_type(self):
   if self.is_company == True:
      self.customer = False
      self.supplier = True
   else :
      self.customer = True
      self.supplier = False
Still nothing

Comment: The is_company field is invisible by default did you changed the view ?

Comment: I'm still in the form view. I just wanted to give a try with this  field because nothing changed with 'company_type'

Comment: are you using the new api in your model ?

Comment: Yes I'm using Odoo V9

Comment: you should not try it with the is_company field . Are you sure about importing your .py file ? Do you have other functionalities that are running ?  Have you restarted your server ? If so please share your code so i try to find the problem.

Comment: I have also tried with "company_type" I have the same result: Actually nothing change even if I check "Company" on my form.
I have restarted the server... :/

Comment: Is the method executed ? if you log a message inside it do you get it ?

Comment: Seems like the method is not executed. I've tried to display a simple message when changing "company_type" but nothing happens. 

@api.onchange('company_type')
@api.multi
def change_company_type(self):
   res = {}
   if self.is_company == 'company':
      self.customer = False
      self.supplier = True
      res = {'warning': {
            'title': _('Warning'),
            'message': _('Test.')}
        }

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old api so use this method instead :

```
def onchange_company_type(self, cr, uid, ids, company_type, context=None):
  return {'value': {'customer': False, 'supplier': True}} if company_type=='person' else {'value': {'customer': True, 'supplier': False}}
```

And in the company_type field in xml file add this attribute

```
on_change="onchange_company_type(company_type)"
```

Comment: Still nothing changes.. How can I use the new api with the onchange method ?

Comment: You need tu put the method inside the mypartner_custom class restart your server and update the module

Answer (score -1):

Override the create method, check the corresponding values, and set like you want:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    if vals['contact'] == "Individual":
        vals['customer'] = True
        vals['supplier'] = False
    elif vals['contact'] == "Company":
        vals['customer'] = False
        vals['supplier'] = True
    return super(res_partner, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

Comment: This will run after saving the record, so if you want to manually select customer and supplier it wont work, what i think he wants is a default.

Comment: thanks for your fast response:
I have tried this on .py of my module but I don't have the expected behavior:

def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    if vals['company_type'] == "person":
        vals['customer'] = True
        vals['supplier'] = False
    elif vals['company_type'] == "company":
        vals['customer'] = False
        vals['supplier'] = True
    return super(res_partner, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)

Comment: @ThinkMAL, what happened? And what behavior did you expect?

Comment: Are you extending the res_partner model?

Comment: @TalesPádua: Exactly as described on my question: If the field "is_company" is changed the fields "supplier" and "customer" change in the form: if company => supplier if not => client